# style a JavaScript onmouseover alert

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code to make the alert appear when i hover over the image;

```
var special_offers = document.getElementsByClassName("special_offer");

//for each special offer
for(i=0;i<special_offers.length;i++){
    var special_offer = special_offers[i];
    special_offer.setAttribute("offer_shown", "0");

    special_offer.onmouseover = function(){
        if( this.getAttribute("offer_shown") == "0" ){
            this.setAttribute("offer_shown", "1");

            alert('This room has the special offer attached to it, please book soon before you miss out!');
        }
    }
```

I wanted to find out how i change this from the bog standard JS alert to a box that i can style, i imagine i'd use some sort of a div.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Search for modal windows. jQuery UI has some you can use. Or you can make your own with an absolute positioned div.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add i'm trying not to use jQuery

Answer (score 2):

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

This is a good resource for creating your own modal window. You can use your function to fire the modal window you created instead of just using alert() to fire up the standard alert.

Comment: Will that work with just normal HTML and CSS as the title on website says HTML5 and CSS3?

Comment: i don't think so friend. sorry

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to direct your message to a div?

Create the div

```
<div id="mySpecialOffer">
   Some Text gets updated
</div>
```

In your js you could then target this id and update with what ever message you would like.

```
document.getElementById("mySpecialOffer").innerHTML = 'some Text';
```

You could even hide the div in css and then unhide with the JS.

Or you can create the HTML...

```
document.getElementById("mySpecialOffer").innerHTML = '<div> Special Offer Div Inserted </div>';
```

This is even easier with jQuery.

Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Not entirely, the alert only appears when i hover over the specific images, but i'd like to do it without jQuery and HTML just through JS. Because what i have now is when i hover over the image it displays the normal alert box i want to replace that normal alert box with my own.

Here is what my website does currently http://www.numyspace.co.uk/~unn_w12001251/accommodation.html

Comment: Seems like what you want is a lightbox? Wow, trying to do this with straight JS. I am not aware of anyway to do this since JS doesnt create an HTML nor CSS. What you need to do is create a function in place of the alert message that fires off a lightbox. It is the modern technique and your users would appreciate it way more. Here is a site that has a simple solution... http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

Comment: As I mentioned about add the document.getElementById("mySpecialOffer).innerHTML = '<div>...</div>'; You can add in all the html and style you want. I would code out a close button and another piece of JS to close the new div. You will need to add in css to style the new div so that it looks like a pop up. The above link is a good example. Let me know if this helps get you on the right track. Again, not sure of any straigt JS method as you will need to add HTML dynamically and style using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is open a whole new window, like a small webpage with that message. That would be the easiest way to go!
Here is a link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

You will want to have the window.open() activated when people mouseover an image.
you can specify the size and positioning of the window, in this case the center of the screen, and a small window.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Nah i don't want to open a new window thats not what i want. I have it exactly how i want it now, but i want my own alert box not the default one.

Comment: This is the easiest solution actually. What you want is a lightbox, but that is far more complex then opening a new window. There is nothing in JS that will give a popup window you can style Keith unless you use a lightbox which is more complex then using a popup window.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnAltman thats kinda what i mean, i wasnt sure how to explain it though!